# Latex and linebreaks: Why does it not hyphenate?

Tags: pdftex, hyphenation

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

This text should not be indented.

This tex should be indented.

This text is veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyYyQyyyyyyyyyyyyQ long, but should not be broken `tween `'y'' and `'long''.
This is not going too well.\  How do I know where the linebreak on the page should go?\ Is there a magic index that I cannot see?\ What is the issue, and where does it appear?\
\centerline{This is the center.}
\end{document}
```

Firstly, Hello and salutations. Secondly, I do not understand why the above input does not hyphenate the extremely long goulash that I intentionally put in. (Yes, I know the quotations are wrong, but I don't think that is the issue.)

The capital Y and the Qs are in the text only for aiding in counting the characters, and they do not appear in the document.

I am three days new to LaTex, and I have been going through the books and articles; no answers.

So, Why?

P.S. I put the `\` in my sentences for a reason. But again, they can't be the error.

Comment: TeX uses a database of hyphenation patterns. It can't hyphenate gibberish, unless you tell it how to do so.

Comment: Maybe you have a reason for ``\ ``, but it's wrong nonetheless. You should declare `\frenchspacing` in the preamble if you don't want extended space after punctuation.

Comment: Where, in your opinion, should hyphenation points be allowed in the string`yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyYyQyyyyyyyyyyyylong`? (Aside: I find it quite surprising that LaTeX found even one hyphenation point.)

Comment: The `\ ` are incorrect also `\centerline` should not be used in LaTeX, the text `This text should not be indented.` should be indented (latex does not indent the first paragraph after a heading, but you have no heading)

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses.  The whole of the input text was running multiple experiments together to see the output.  I know that it is not scientific, but I was trusting that the trials would not affect each other.

Comment: That the hyphenation could not take place because the word is gibberish was one of the points of using the input that I did.  Is there a way to see if the word will have problems before compilation, or only by using trial and error.

Comment: AFAIK, only trial and error is guaranteed.  Looking for horizontal overflow in the log file is one way to locate problems that were not obvious. You can also use draft mode with overflow rule. And, you can add a custom hyphenation pattern for something not understood by the dictionary patterns..

Comment: One more thing to note. Why do you expect that first line to not be indented? The paragraph following a sectioning command )\chapter, \section, etc.) is usually not indented but you are not using one.

Answer (score 1):

TeX is not able to hyphen gibberish, unless by chance it finds one or more of the preloaded patterns in the pseudowords.

You can check TeX's idea of hyphenation with the `testhyphen` package. If no good point is found, you have to help TeX by adding `\-` in appropriate spots or by defining hyphenation exceptions.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{testhyphens}

\begin{document}

\section{Check hyphens}

\begin{checkhyphens}
veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyYyQyyyyyyyyyyyyQ
\end{checkhyphens}

\section{Text}

This text should not be indented.

This tex should be indented.

This text is veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr 
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyYyQyyyyyyyyyyyyQ long, but should not be broken 'tween 
``y'' and ``long''. This is not going too well.  How do I know where the 
linebreak on the page should go? Is there a magic index that I cannot see? 
What is the issue, and where does it appear?
\begin{center}
This is the center.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{testhyphens}

\hyphenation{
  veeeeeeee-eeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrr-rrrrrr-rrrrrr-rrrrrrrrr-rrrrrrrrrrrrrr
  yyyyyyyyy-yyyyyyy-yyyyyy-YyQyy-yyyyyyyyyyQ
}

\begin{document}

\section{Check hyphens}

\begin{checkhyphens}
veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyYyQyyyyyyyyyyyyQ
\end{checkhyphens}

\section{Text}

This text should not be indented.

This tex should be indented.

This text is veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr 
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyYyQyyyyyyyyyyyyQ long, but should not be broken 'tween 
``y'' and ``long''. This is not going too well.  How do I know where the 
linebreak on the page should go? Is there a magic index that I cannot see? 
What is the issue, and where does it appear?
\begin{center}
This is the center.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A few other points.

1. The first paragraph *after a sectional title* is not indented.
2. Opening quotes are input with ``` `` ```, not with `` `' ``.
3. The apostrophe before `twen` should be `'`.
4. `\centerline` is not a LaTeX command.
5. If you don't want extended space after punctuation, declare `\frenchspacing` in the preamble.

Answer (score 1):

Since it has not been mentioned: You can declare hyphenation pattern for unusual words. For example, here is the start of my custom `hyphenation.tex`, which I `\input` into all my documents:

```
\hyphenation{
acet-a-mi-no-phen
ace-tyl-cho-lin-ester-ase
ace-tyl-cho-line
ace-tyl-glu-cos-amine
ade-no-syl-me-thi-o-nine
...
}
```

Every dash in every listed word becomes potential break point for hyphenation. Works really well.